# schedule function return until ajax is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Example of producing!
This is the code used in ajax! I want to schedule the returning of `g_text` until the ajax is done.

```
g_text = '@' + text;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/pages/profile/actions.php?action=isusername',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            uname: text,
        }
    }).done(function(result) {
        if (result == "true") {
            g_text = '<a target="_blank" href="/?page=profile&base=' + text + '">' + '@' + text + '</a>';
        }
    });
    return g_text;
```

Comment: This question has been asked a lot of times. Here, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Sorry, didn't take time to search!